# Como adicionar um intervalo de inserção de dados no banco com Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Eu estou tendo o seguinte problema, qualquer botão no meu projeto que leva o usuário a inserir alguma informação na base de dados, caso seja apertado várias vezes rapidamente (sem dar tempo para a página atualizar e exibir os dados), ele insere várias vezes o mesmo dado que foi escrito nos inputs na base de dados.

[image: Comentários repetidos]

Não sei se o Laravel possui algo contra falhas deste tipo, mas se não possuir, acredito que adicionando um intervalo de alguns segundos ou minutos para cada próxima inserção resolveria, alguém sabe alguma solução para isso?

**Versão do Laravel usada:** 5.6

Comment: Você pode bloquear o botão após o click, já pensou nisso?

Comment: porque é que voce no fim da inserção nao reenvia o user para outra pagina?

Comment: É justamente isso que estou falando, não dá tempo de reenviar, se ficar apertando varias vezes ele flooda com várias inserções, a página não tem tempo de carregar